# General workflow for Github

Tags: github

I am new to Github. I've read lots of Github docs but still confused on the general work flow when cooperating with many on a large project. My questions is:

1. I clone a repo, create my branch and edit on my code. While I am working, someone else updated the origin/master. How should I do to update my local branch with master while not losing my current edited code? e.g., someone created another folder and ask me to put my edited code in the folder?
2. Assume the above question is solved, before I make the PR, do I have to check if someone has changed master, update with me and then make the PR?

Thank you for your answers. It would be great if you could list the git command workflow.

Comment: (1) You either merge the master into your branch, or rebase your branch onto master. (2) Yes, it's better to do so.

Comment: Can you elaborate more precisely on how rebase my branch onto master?@HolyBlackCat

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase